# Debian set very low display resolution

Tags: xrandr, resolution

I have a very small display, 128 to 72 pixels, and I want to set the display resolution to 128x72, is that possible?

Once I set the screen resolution with `xrandr` to 128x72 pixels, I only get gray snow.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include i) the exact `xrandr` command you tried and ii) your hardware details. What machine is this? What display? What graphics card? Which graphics driver?